# Deploy new stack by using Docker Engine API

Tags: docker

I have looked into the [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/) (v1.37) and have found its method in close relationship to `docker` commands, as one would expect. For instance, the API offers a method `GET /nodes` and there is a command `docker node`.

However, I have not yet found an equivalent to `docker stack` in the current API. So is it possible to deploy (from a compose file) by using this API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is intentionally missing so that people will pay for some sort of enterprise or cloud services. I would really like this to work as well -- I'd like to use the Docker.DotNet package to do a stack deploy on a swarm manager from a remote C# application. Unfortunately, you'll have to manually create all networks, volumes, and containers through the API since the stack functions are not made available.

Comment: @KyleP Thx for your comment. If you want to write it up as an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Technically it is possible, but would require to replicate steps performed by CLI when services and other moving parts are created.

---

Docker Stack is similar to Docker Compose and they both are high-level commands that use manifest file to abstract (or automate) some of the actions needed to start containers and services. This means they require multiple API calls to do their job and *I assume* this is why they both don’t have respective endpoints in Docker Engine API.

If we look at [`docker stack deploy` command implementation](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/3fb4fb83dfb5db0c0753a8316f21aea54dab32c5/cli/command/stack/swarm/deploy_composefile.go#L19-L64), it performs following steps:

- validates external networks existence;
- creates stack networks;
- creates stack secrets;
- creates stack configs, and;
- deploys services.

It also generates and injects labels to allow itself to find created stack parts in future, e.g. to destroy the stack.

I haven’t dug deeper; maybe there are other “hidden” actions.

All in all, it should be possible to perform all the necessary steps via Docker Engine API and make Docker see the stack.

To verify the theory, I’ve ran following command to create a service with Docker Stack internal labels and Docker Stack style name:

```
docker service create \
  --label com.docker.stack.image="traefik/whoami" \
  --label com.docker.stack.namespace="whoami"
  --mode replicated \
  --name whoami_whoami \
  --replicas=1 \
  traefik/whoami
```

Executing `docker stack ls` then prints the following:

```
NAME      SERVICES   ORCHESTRATOR
whoami    1          Swarm
```

Seems to do the job.

I assume other resources (networks, secrets, configs) must be labeled too, but it still looks doable if needed.